# Mystery of the broken Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Note: I'm using an M1 Apple Silicon MacBook

*Not sure if this is linked:*
So I was using Atom to do some CSS editing last night. When trying to close it, Atom wouldn't close and the computer actually crashed. The file wasn't saved anywhere and was just a throw away copy paste editing file.

Today I started up my computer and opened Google Chrome and everything is busted. I've attached some images, one showing what it looks like in the inspect window, with a giant red box around everything, this has not been added, this is what it looks like in my Chrome > Dev Tools. It seems like the CSS of Chrome has been damaged in some way? I'm not a very experienced programmer.

I tried to reinstall Chrome and delete all Chrome Application Support files but the issue remained.

Also checked the Dev Tools > More Tools > Changes window

Does anyone know how this is happening?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks malware. Do you have antivirus installed ? I recommend Kaspersky Total Security for Mac.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Will do a full scan now and see if anything comes up.

Comment: @Niloct Did a scan and nothing was found

Comment: Disable hardware acceleration in chrome settings: 'Command + ,' then search in the blue bar for 'hardware', a switch will appear, turn if off and restart Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed this with the following:**

Deleting chrome from Applications and emptying bin

Did a search for all files with "Google" and deleted 3 remaining files named "Google".

Deleted the Google files found in Application Support

Ran an Avast scan (found nothing)

Did a full cache/history clear

Comment: Didnt help me. Seems to be a build issue with `Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (arm64)`